# What does ${/*var in here*/} do. I cannot find any results anywhere

Tags: php

This is a very stupid question but for the life of me i cannot figure our what this does. And from past experience if you don't know then ask or forever stay stupid
code eg

```
foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    ${$key.'Count'} = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a feature called "variable variables" (you will be more successful searching for that term). The manual is not the best, but it does cover your example. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: There is a very useful PHP tutorial linked in the comments for the Stack Overflow PHP tag.

Comment: It's important to note that you should try to refrain from using variable variables wherever possible - they're ugly and can be difficult to follow and understand. Sometimes, however, you have no choice

Comment: @Bojangles when do you have no choice?

Comment: Well the main reason i am asking is because i am editing someone else s script and this section made it so hard to follow and understand what he tried to do. Now i know thanks all for the swift responses

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Err... you've got me there. I added that last sentence as a preemptive measure against people possibly saying "but actually there are some times when you need it". I've needed it occasionally, but very rarely

Comment: Well checking the script that i am busy with it was not needed at all. it served no purpose so i removed it. I just thought before i remove it let me ask first what it does.

Comment: @Bojangles it can make code shorter and fancier but I don't think you really need it

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses I absolutely agree. I would much rather have longer code than use variable variables. I think the only time I used it was in a config method of a class to do things like `public function set($key, $val) { $this->conf->$key = $val; }` but that's not really the same

Comment: @Bojangles. I use that a lot and no its not the same because you are defining class vars and its not that hard to see or read what you did there. but the example i supplied in my question above made absolutely no sense until i asked. With $this->conf->$key = $val; you can still see what ever is set as key become a class variable. Still hard to trace and debug.

Comment: I agree completely. It takes me quite a while to wrap my head around code using variable variables. They really should never have been introduced except to support defining class variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). The resultant string inside the braces is used as the name of the variable. So if you have the following:

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar');

foreach( $arr as $key => $val ) {
    ${$key.'Count'} = 0;
}
```

There will now be a variable `$fooCount`, with the value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are used to explicitly set the end of a variable name.

In your specific case, the variable name is being created dynamically:

```
${$key.'Count'} // $myKeyCount
```

It can also be used to specify the end of a non-dynamically named variable:

```
echo "My string has {$example}00.00 things"; // where I write out a value 100 times bigger
```

Comment: the last example doesn't have anything to do with this, in my opinion. can you explain yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

you can set a var with that with an variable name so

```
$varName = 'test'
${$varName}  = "Hello world!";
echo $test;
```

will show

```
 Hello world!
```